# Fast and maintainable way of implementing character to string lookup table (in Java)

Tags: java, data-structures

The goal is to map a string to a character. The issue is that non-ascii characters are also valid. So I am not able to think of what my hash function would be.

Comment: You don't need to.  Just cast it to an int.  (It's what Character.hashCode does.). Also, why are you not using HashMap which will take care of this for you?

Comment: You can't have a hash function without collision if the hash size is less than the input.